# Angular 6 - Use user location with API (OpenLayers)

Tags: javascript, angular, api, openlayers

I'm programming a map with [Angular](https://angular.io/) (6) and [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) (4.6.5) where the goal is firstly to retrieve user geolocation. I'm using a french [API](https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/api) provided by the French Government allowing to perform queries and return GeoJSON files.

I'm stuck on how to do it, I have created an Angular [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxqjux) where I have created an interface with my map and buttons.

In the API link there is some HTTP request like `http 'https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/?q=8 bd du port'`. In my example I'm not using these http requests, only a constant url : is that a problem ?

I have only the possibility to constrct the request but how can I retrieve the GeoJSON file constrcted by the request ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call a function in angular on click with `(click)="myFunction()"`.